# samba printing not working from Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: printing, samba

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 and tried 19.04, 19.10 but I was unable to connect to a Windows printer via Samba from Ubuntu. I was using Ubuntu 16.04 and I was able to connect to Windows 8 connected Canon MF3010 printer using Windows network printer via Samba.

The problem with Ubuntu 18.04, 19.04 and 19.10 is as follows:

1. I have installed all the required packages for Samba and used "add printer".
2. When I click on option add network printer via Samba and tried to browse printer, it always showed "no print share found".
3. After that I figured out the problem by adding a line `client max protocol =NT1` in the Global section of samba configuration file.
4. After that I can browse the print share and find the printer
5. I added the printer and when I go through select printer driver I can't find it in any of the above Ubuntu versions (but i can found it in Ubuntu 16.04 and no above step is required for browsing printer via Samba)
6. Then I downloaded and installed printer driver for Ubunutu and then driver come up at add printer wizard but after adding I tried to print test page then it shows processing no errors anywhere, and i can't print it.

In Ubuntu 16.04 works without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I know there is a configuration file that details in the smb.conf a configured directory which specifies where Windows machines with go to get print drivers for samba/cups you probably don't have that setup or populated.